# Get single value from dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe A:

```
       's'   'S'   'T'
 0     'abc'  'a'   12
 1     'def'  'b'   15
 2     'abc'  'b'   1.4
```

Now I want to have the value of 'T' where 's' == 'abc' and 'S' == 'b'

So I tried:

```
  idx = (A['s'] == 'abc') & (A['S'] == 'b')
```

but I see .get_value() is depricated and:

```
 number = A.at[idx,'T']
```

gives this error:

```
ValueError: At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers
```

EDIT:

```
 number = A.loc[idx, 'T']
```

returns a dataframe and not the value (integer or float)

```
 print(number)

 2    1.4
 Name: T, dtype: float64
```

When doing this:

```
 number2 = 1.3
 if (number != number2):
```

I get:

```
  ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After filtering you get `one item Series`, so for select first value is possible use `iat`:

```
number = A.loc[idx,'T'].iat[0]
print (number)
14
```

But if mask return more values, get:

```
print (A)
     s  S   T
0  abc  a  12
1  abc  b  15
2  abc  b  14

idx = (A['s'] == 'abc') & (A['S'] == 'b')
print (idx)
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool

number = A.loc[idx,'T']
print (number)
1    15
2    14
Name: T, dtype: int64
```

Here is possible use same aproach - select first value of condition:

```
number = A.loc[idx,'T'].iat[0]
print (number)
15
```

Answer (score 3):

The above will throw an error of idx not defined, the default way to access index is **dataframe.index** and not idx

It should rather be

```
number = A.loc[A.index,'T'].iat[0]
```